# Implementing `elem` with foldLeft

Tags: scala, fold

I'm working on Learn You a Haskell. On the "fold" section, I need to implement `elem` (given an element, find out if it's in the list - True or False).

```
def myElem(a: Char, as: List[Char]): Boolean = as match {
   case Nil => false
   case x::Nil => println(x); if(x == a) true else false
   case x::_ => println(x); as.foldLeft(false){ (_, elem) => 
                   if(a == elem) true
                   else myElem(a, as.tail)

   }
}
```

However, it's failing on a simple example:

```
scala> myElem('a', "ab".toList)
a
b
res8: Boolean = false
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, as extra, I'd appreciate any suggestion on improvement of this code.

As an aside, I would think a `find` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple implementation:

```
  def elem[A](a: A, as: List[A]): Boolean = as match {
    case Nil => false
    case h :: t => (h == a) || elem(a, t)
  }
```

Also, instead of `find` you could use `exists`:

```
def elem[A](a: A, as: List[A]) = as.exists(_ == a)
```

If you want to `foldLeft` you can, but you'll still traverse the whole list instead of stopping early:

```
  def elem[A](a: A, as: List[A]) = 
    as.foldLeft(false)((bool, value) => bool || value == a)
```

Comment: Yes - it's clean - thanks. what about using `foldLeft` though?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I updated the answer, you can use foldLeft, but I wouldn't if your lists are long.

Comment: Looking at the LYAH version that I converted to Scala: `def myElem[A](a: A, as: List[A]): Boolean = {
  as.foldLeft(false){ (acc, elem) => if(elem == a) true else acc }
}`, I like your version too as it will short-circuit if the `accumulator` (or `bool` as you call it) is true.